# Upgrade Error 'preflight finished with "false" result'

Tags: joomla-4.x, upgrade

I was upgrading my site today from Joomla 4.3.4 to 4.4.2. I'm using PHP 8.1.27

I downloaded the official zip upgrade package from here https://downloads.joomla.org/cms/joomla4/4-4-2 and uploaded through the admin area.

When the upgrade completed I was presented with the following error.

[image]

My log files how the following;

```
2024-02-06T13:25:10+00:00   INFO 143.117.194.243    update  Starting installation of new version.
2024-02-06T13:25:13+00:00   INFO 143.117.194.243    update  Finalising installation.
2024-02-06T13:25:13+00:00   ERROR 143.117.194.243   update  An error has occurred while running "JoomlaInstallerScript::preflight". Code: 0. Message: Script::preflight finished with "false" result..
2024-02-06T13:25:13+00:00   WARNING 143.117.194.243 jerror  Extension Install: Custom install routine failure.
2024-02-06T13:25:13+00:00   INFO 143.117.194.243    update  Cleaning up after installation.
2024-02-06T13:25:13+00:00   INFO 143.117.194.243    update  Update to version 4.4.2 is complete.
```

I returned to the dashboard, and my website appears to be working as expected as it's on v4.4.2

I've tried to re-install the package a second time and same error.

Any ideas what's goin on?